# Issue with Magento Categories - redirects from URL to home

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am having a very strange issue with Magento.

I skinned the install for a client, and everything has been working fine. I used a pre-built theme for this skin, and made some minor changes - but none at all to the system, or core files of Magento.

The issue I am facing is that anything I go to www.siteexample.com/shop/category/view/id/9 for example, or it's Rewrite URL of www.siteexample.com/shirts.html - it redirects to the homepage, or gives me a 404.

Going directly to a product for example, works just fine.

Has anyone ever faced a similar issue? There is not much else I can offer. If there is a log that I can check to provide more info, please let me know and I will provide it.

Thanks in advance. Really puzzling.

Comment: check var/system.log file.

Comment: Truncate the core_url_rewrite table before that take backup of this table.Delete all files from var/locks.Reindex 'Catalog URL Rewrites' from admin.

Comment: Hi monojit. Tried all of the above. Still getting a 404. I can go directly to a product, but it refuses to give me a category listing of the products in a grid/list.

Comment: can you share the url of your site.

Comment: what is the url format of your product page link in category listing page? how can u go directly to the product page? both url format is same or not?

Comment: hi monojit. i took a stock install and skinned it with a particular theme the link is www dot papertrails718 dot com slash shop. i was able to check the rewrite URL's and it showed me the links it created for products and they work fine. maybe this is some theme limitation? i am not sure what is going on. never had this problem with magento

Comment: also, here is a link to an image which can show you a link to get to each product. [link](http://www.papertrails718.com/magento.png) - and one other note - with any other stock implementation, the URL key field in Categories stays present, and on this one, they disappear.

Comment: i am unable to see your category listing page. there is no any link for category listing page in navigation menu.how can i see? product page working fine.

Comment: Actually i never used custom magento rewrite hence gone through http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/modules_reference/english/mage_adminhtml/urlrewrite/index.But i have tested it on my site,perfectly works for me.create a new product and after creating custom rewrite for this particular product, check it first. Or u may create another question in stack by heading "magento custom rewite not working" or something like that.let me know the current status.

Comment: check properly product page link on category page product list.I think u doing something wrong.

Comment: hi monojit. maybe i wasn't clear. these rewrites work fine. the issue is with my question above: the CATEGORY links do not work: custom NOR default (url.com/shop/catalog/category/view/id/4) - this is my issue. try one of these with [link](papertrails718.com/shop/) - if you try to go to any default category (active are 8,9,10,11,13) link it will redirect home rather than listing the products.

Comment: in your navigation menu i can't see any link for category page.it shows '#'. I have tried  http://url.com/shop/catalog/category/view/id/11 as well it shows 404 page.create new category and check.

Comment: hi monojit - i know. this is the problem! it shows 404 or if i re-write indexes, it will simply sometimes redirect to home - but none of my categories want to show! when i come to add a re-write for them, it gives me an error as well, saying "this product is not associate with the current store" - it makes zero sense. it is WHY i need this to work, so i can add these links to my custom menu bar. they are # because these links are currently not working. maybe we can talk off here and you can assist me? maybe we can work something out. need to fix this asap

Comment: okk.. r using more than one store? u can send me mail as well at banik.monojit@gmail.com.send me admin user name password as well.will check.

Comment: okk.. cool..what was the problem? you may answer here and close the topic.